# Last digit of a number

Tags: modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients, factorial, decimal-expansion

I was currently solving a question of permutations and in that I had to find the total ways of something. The answer was ${8\choose 4}$ which has last digit $0$ .

A random thought that came to my mind was that whether we had a manual way to compute the last digit of a number such as ${369\choose 233}$ . I know after $4!$ all have last digit $0$ but somehow it might be possible that it gets cancelled and we have last digit as $5$. I know basics of modular algebra but not much in deep so can you guys help. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but is the bracket notation for number of permutations or for combinations?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN: This is the standard notation for a [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $\binom nk$, which counts the number of $k$-combinations of $n$ elements.

Comment: Combinations are represented by it

Comment: @joriki@Archis Welankar Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The remainder of binomial coefficients with respect to primes is given by [Lucas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas'_theorem): For non-negative integers $m$ and $n$ and a prime $p$,

$$\binom{m}{n}\equiv\prod_{i=0}^k\binom{m_i}{n_i}\bmod p\;,$$

where $m_i$ and $n_i$ are the $i$-th digits of $m$ and $n$, respectively. To find the last digit of a binomial coefficient, we need its remainders modulo $2$ and $5$. For $\binom84$ we have

\begin{align}
8_{10}&=1000_2\;,\\
4_{10}&=100_2\;,\\
8_{10}&=13_5\;,\\
4_{10}&=4_5\;,
\end{align}

so

$$
\binom84\equiv\binom00\binom00\binom01\binom10\equiv0\bmod2
$$

and

$$
\binom84\equiv\binom34\binom10\equiv0\bmod5\;,
$$

confirming that $\binom84\equiv0\bmod10$. For $\binom{369}{233}$ we have

\begin{align}
369_{10}&=101110001_2\;,\\
233_{10}&=11101001_2\;,\\
369_{10}&=2434_5\;,\\
233_{10}&=1413_5\;,
\end{align}

so

$$
\binom{369}{233}\equiv\binom11\binom00\binom00\binom01\binom10\binom11\binom11\binom01\binom10\equiv0\bmod2
$$

and
$$\binom{369}{233}\equiv\binom43\binom31\binom44\binom21\bmod5\equiv4\bmod5\;,$$

yielding $\binom{369}{233}\equiv4\bmod10$, and indeed $\binom{369}{233}$ is

```
129169640332119737443677929159655724937368247006147295954110094567417591725745376306913730846211971776964.
```

Comment: If we were trying to find if it was $0$, which was your previous answer, couldn't we also just check how much trailing $0$s the above and the below has(without using Lucas's Theorem)?

Comment: @MXYMXY: No, it's not just the number of trailing $0$s. The remainder with respect to $p$ is zero if and only if some digit of $m$ (in base $p$) is greater than the corresponding digit of $n$. (This is a direct corollary of Lucas' theorem.)

Comment: Thanks thats really good way using binary